# Ошибка в логических операторах C++

Tags: c++

Задача - сделать программу, которая преобразует входящий массив, заменяя два последовательно стоящих нуля (00) на 1. Например, 10010 на 1110

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int in[8], out[8], i;

    cout << "In:" << endl;    //Входящий поток

    for (i=0;i<8;i++) //Ввод потока
    {
        cout << "In[" << i << "]="; cin >> in[i];
        if (in[i]!=0 && in[i]!= 1)
        {
            cout << "Incorrect In. Only 0 and 1 permitted." << endl; exit(0);
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
        cout << in[i];
    cout << endl << endl << "Out:" << endl;

    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        int j=0;
        if(in[i]==1)
        {out[j]=1; j++;}

        if(in[i]==0)
        {
            if (in[i+1]==1)
            {
                out[j]=0; j++;
            }
            if (in[i+1]==0)
            {
                out[j]=1; j++; i++; //Где-то тут жесткий косяк
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    for (i=0; i<j; i++)
        cout << out[i];

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод игнорирует мой i++ в строке с комментарием про косяк, выглядит не очень [image: не очень]

**Вопрос очевиден**, почему i++ игнорируется и как это заставить работать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а если 000 то что должно быть?

Comment: 10, обработка идет слева направо.

Comment: ну у вас 110 будет, вам разобраться надо или просто код рабочий?

Comment: Разобраться, ибо я искренне не осознаю где косяк. С плюсами только знакомлюсь.

Comment: Приведенный фрагмент вообще не должен компилироваться, т.к. переменная j используется вне своей области видимости. А еще должно быть предупреждение, что дважды объявлена i

Comment: Пардон, j только из спортивного интереса перенес, так она глобальная. И где вы видите два объявления i?

Comment: ищите косяк в другом месте, у меня приведённый код работает, ну с учётом того, что объявление j перенёс в main

Comment: @ЭдуардИзмалков т.е. вас не смущает что тут вся логика нарушена?

Comment: @pavel а чем она нарушена? код полностью выполняет то, что требуется автору.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала отформатируем

```
if(in[i]==1){
    out[j]=1; 
    j++;
} else {
  if (in[i+1]==1){
      out[j]=0; 
      j++;
  } else {
      out[j]=1; 
      j++; 
      i++;
  }
```

Если была единица то она и останется, окей.
Если у нас 0, то смотрим следующий символ - уже нельзя так, мы должны знать количество *предыдущих* 0 ещё... Нужно менять логику. Памяти нам не жалко, поэтому заводим переменную.

```
int countZero = 0;
...
else {
    countZero++;
    if (countZero&1) ;//ничего не нужно делать
    else //к ответу добавить 1
```

Теперь её нужно корректно сбрасывать.

```
if(in[i]==1){
   countZero = 0;
```

Но мы тереяем нечётные 0. Теперь всё в сборе. Бонус сразу можно выводить без массива  и все элементы читаются ровно 1 раз.

```
bool countZero = 0;
for (int i =0; i<8;i++){

    if(a[i]){
        if (countZero)
            cout << 0;
        countZero = 0;
        cout << 1;
    } else {
        countZero ^=1;
        if (!countZero)
            cout << 1;
    }
}
if (countZero)
    cout << 0;
cout << endl;
```

Пример: http://ideone.com/HJmWrN